# How to strongly type string to custom data type

Tags: typescript

I use strings to represent my data and pass it around.
Before using it I have to parse it and get the data out of string.
I don't want to check for parse errors on runtime.

How can I give a special type to strings only produced by factory functions and make sure they fail on any other string types.

```
type MyData = string

let i = 0
function gen_id(): MyData {
    return `hello__${i}`
}

function hello(_: MyData) {
    console.log(_.split('__')[1])
}

hello(gen_id())

hello('world') // I want this to give compile error
```

Currently this doesn't produce an compile error.

Comment: Are the strings ALWAYS going to be of the form `"hello__..."`?

Comment: yes, i control the generator function to be custom format, and I control the usage of it, expecting that specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has support for string template literals:

```
type MyData = `${string}__${number}`

let i = 0
function gen_id(): MyData {
    return `hello__${i}`
}

function hello(_: MyData) {
    console.log(_.split('__')[1])
}

hello(gen_id())

hello('world') // Argument of type '"world"' is not assignable to parameter of type '`${string}__${number}`'.(2345)
```

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYioF4oAMAkBvAzsAE4CWAdgOYC+A+jXmQK4C2ARhEVZgFDcA2EYFBLooABm4AzRmQDGwEgHsyUChDI0SAEwAUASgBcsBMlS5uUS1CKDGRFZgAWEPn0V08JLtyq9pchWUoZ1dFHRojOCQUPShzKyhZZXxFAQA6NwpwtPwwPhJgHQByOiK9AG0ARgBdPR9eELcdNQ1tfTruRrCigHdFIj4tMqgAehGoAEEiChZ1IUVJKFBIKCKAIj6BrTWi4XwoMkUhRHx8EgoyRFYBJcUoMEQiRGZBDigFpfBoIpwCYnJqB5cEw2BwuEU0joAEwAZgALABWPRAA)

Comment: well the data inside string is like json data so not that simple.

Comment: But i guess i could compose these Types inside string literals?

Comment: Yes it works, can you please edit your answer to this nested types so I can accept https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnKBeKADCCD2cAkBvAOwFcBbAIwwF9UAoG0SKAWRABEBDYd5NfAZ2BwAlgQDmlAPoT8xclSn54canQA2EYFCE8ADDQBmRAgGNgQzASiiIBCUIAmACgCUALmZtO3PDSh+ocBpEcJaoABYQqqqYCnhCkhIYcNgAzLSUdIYmZhZQEVGYjhLuLBxczlA+-lDGFnyY6gB00aJFjXxgqkLAjgDkUr3OANoAjAC6zjQZNPnRjta2Di6TM5FzvQDu2Kr2g1AA9PtQAIJwoqQ2mpj6UAzQvQBEW3A7D71afFAEmJrsfHxCUQEdhkdS3TBQMDsODsEgaDBQa63cD3VD8QQicSxWQUZSoXqNRwAJhSABYAKzOIA

Comment: @eguneys It might be best that I not edit my answer. There was no mention of the `Err` component in your question at the time that i wrote my answer. Additionally, given that you already added the code as a comment, everything is already here.

Comment: Can you make this typecheck somehow https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwE4wLwwAwwD4wIw4wBMwpAxgPYB2AziDAGYIA2UNaMA2gOQCG3AGhjcARoOFluAXRi92lWiFLhoMAGIcVUCg0Ys2nREinlqdGEl5UA1u3Q8847kScBmabPlmloSLABKmn46Fla2hsgmwKz0CBwAtHjRUPRIAFwwgeiWNjScCFFaMAAKHAAGACQA3moAvtX+tWWkMTAA+rwZGuh83Mn0bSIZWcKO-TAQGaXoHTAA1O0iQA

Comment: @eguneys Yes: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwE4wLwwAwwD4wIw4wBMwpAxgPYB2AziDAGYIA2UNaMA2gOQCG3AGhjcARoOFluAXRi92lWiFLhoMAGIcVUCg0Ys2nREinlqdGEl5UA1u3Q8847kScBmabPlmloSLABKmn46Fla2hsgmwKz0CBwAtHjRUPRIAFwwgeiWNjScCFFaMAAKHAAGACQA3moAvtX+tWWkMTAA+rwZGuh83Mn0bSIZWcKO-TAQGaXolVUd9XMiTUA

Comment: In general, avoid using `+` for string concats, only use string templates. It's faster and easier to typecheck.

Comment: what about this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwE4wLwwAwwD4wIw4wBMwpAxgPYB2AziDAGYIA2UNaMA2gOQCG3AGhjcARoOFluAXRi92lWiFLhoMAGIcVUCg0Ys2nREinlqdGEl5UA1u3Q8847kScBmabPlmloSLABKmn46Fla2hsgmwKz0CBwAtHjRUPRIAFwwgeiWNjScCFFaMAAKHAAGACQA3moAvtX+tWWkMTAA+rwZGuh83Mn0bSIZWcKO-TAQGaXolVUd9XMiTS0pExQ0NBkAgkiWYAA8O3v7xQB8pxxMrDQAdAC2vBAAFFewqBc5tvePT59oF7NXgtPk0AJSgoA

Comment: You should ask these as separate questions, but they're quite short. So here you go: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwE4wLwwAwwD4wIw4wBMwpAxgPYB2AziDAGYIA2UNaMA2gOQCG3AGhjcARoOFluAXRi92lWiFLhoMAGIcVUCg0Ys2nREinlqdGEl5UA1u3Q8847kScBmabPlmloSLABKmn46Fla2hsgmwKz0CBwAtHjRUPRIAFwwgeiWNjScCFFaMAAKHAAGACQA3moAvtX+tWWkMTAA+rwZGuh83Mn0bSIZWcKO-TAQGaXolVUd9XMiTS0pExQ0NBkAgkiWYAA8O3v7xQB8pxxMrDQAdAC2vBAAFFewqBc5tvePT59oF7NXgtPk1PDAFHQAJSQoA

Answer (score 1):

> How can I give a special type to strings only produced by factory functions and make sure they fail on any other string types.

You want a string that's a special string, that only comes from a factory function. You are describing type branding.

You make a branded type by intersecting it without something that should only be knowable to the type itself.

A brand may look like:

```
const idBrand = Symbol('idBrand')
type MyData = string & { [idBrand]: true }

// or: string & { __brand: 'fancystring' }
// or: string & { brand: idBrand }
// point is string & some spicy sprinkle.

// I like symbols as keys since they can't clash with any existing properties
// and you don't want them in autocomplete suggestions.

const brandedStringA: MyData = 'asdf' // error
const brandedStringB: MyData = 'asdf' as MyData // fine
```

With that you can make a factory like:

```
let i = 0
function gen_id(): MyData {
    return `hello__${i}` as MyData
}
```

Which works as you expect:

```
function hello(_: MyData) {
    console.log(_.split('__')[1])
}

hello(gen_id()) // fine

hello('world') // error
hello('hello__123') // error
```

A value of type `MyData` can still be used anywhere that a `string` can, but you can't pass a plain `string` to something that needs a `MyData`. It must come from the factory function for that.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgEwEICcCGYEwLwwMoCeAtgEYgA2AFAOSKoYLUCUAUC1AQA4CmMAsgQAiaKGhwxoKOGADmMAGQwA3jADaddJgC6ALhhQUAV14BfNuW6w44gAwsAZobDAoccDBncwAfUSUmegLCososMOEwKJaGKGAwAAYAFtzk5CDe3gAkSnAm8TBoEPxCImgsZg5OLm5xyakglN6BJaJMoREwoJAU3AB0aTKNvRCc5HBQNBnMqgCMWqwVdWmUnj5+TG0A9Jsw9tLcLEsN1ADuICjkjFs73Cgo54cpy9RHGTMATADMzDDbMLf3FAsIA)